# Input email exibir apenas sugestões para EMAILS

Tags: html, input, magento

Olá, eu tenho um input email e para facilitar a digitação e tudo mais eu gostaria de uma "auto sugestão", mas ele está mostrando tudo o que eu já digitei com a letra G, por exemplo, incluindo nomes, coisas, emails e etc, eu gostaria de quando eu clicar no campo do e-mail ele me de a sugestão de apenas e-mails que eu já digitei, alguém saberia como fazer isso? E gostaria de adicionar uma validação, para ver se o usuário digitou com @dominio.com, e fizesse essa validação no blur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme pedido no comentário <sub>"Você saberia como faço para desabilitar o botão do formulário ao aparecer a mensagem?"</sub> na resposta do `Damon Dudek`,
e pelas razões apresentadas no comentario dessa minha resposta <sub>"Por que é um formulário de contato, então se o cliente digitar um e-mail errado e mesmo assim aparecer a mensagem ele ainda pode clicar em enviar e mandar a mensagem por um e-mail inexistente, desabilitando o botão ao ter um e-mail invalido ele não conseguiria enviar!"</sub>

não é necessário desabilitar o botão do formulário ao aparecer a mensagem, basta colocar a validação nele também!!

**Metodo blur no `input id='email'` e click no `button type='submit'`**

```js
function validateEmail(email) {
var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return re.test(email);
}

function validate() {
  $("#result").text("");
  var email = $("#email").val();
  if (validateEmail(email)) {
//$("#result").text(email + " é valido :)");
//$("#result").css("color", "green");
return true;
  } else {
$("#result").text(email + " não é válido :(");
$("#result").css("color", "red");
return false;
  }
  
}

$(".validate").bind("blur", validate);
$("#validate").bind("click", validate);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="https://pt.stackoverflow.com/unanswered">
  <p>email:</p>
  <input id='email' class='validate'>
  <button type='submit' id='validate'>Submit!</button>
</form>

<h2 id='result'></h2>
```

> O input type="email" não é suportado por IE9 e anteriores e Safari.
>
> O Safari da Apple tem o segundo lugar dos navegadores mais usados, com 25,4 por cento  [**Fonte**](http://www.zdnet.com/article/chrome-is-the-most-popular-web-browser-of-all/)

[image: stats navegadores]

E aqui outra estatística não menos desprezível para o Safari [**Fonte**](https://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php)

[image: stats navegadores]

Comment: É basicamente isso, mas o botão não está fazendo nada, ele não envia o formulário.

Comment: @GustavoSouza editei a resposta, veja lá

Comment: Resolveu para mim, muito obrigado cara!!!

Comment: @GustavoSouza porque você queria desabilitar o botão do formulário ao aparecer a mensagem?

Comment: Por que é um formulário de contato, então se o cliente digitar um e-mail errado e mesmo assim aparecer a mensagem ele ainda pode clicar em enviar e mandar a mensagem por um e-mail inexistente, desabilitando o botão ao ter um e-mail invalido ele não conseguiria enviar!

Answer (score 2):

As sugestões de e-mails para um campo de e-mail são feitas automáticamente pelos navegadores, basta você dar o nome de email para o teu input.

Enquanto a validação de e-mail, já existe um recurso nativo do HMTL5, basta definir o seu input com o type email:

```
<input type="email" name="email" />
```

Input types:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

Comment: Eu já utilizo isso no meu input, mas quando digito outras coisas que não sejam e-mail e dou "submit" ele me devolve os valores, ou no caso seria, se eu digitar outros valores no campo email, ele vai salvar aqueles valores achando que é email?

Comment: Sim vai, normal, quem gerencia essas sugestões é o próprio usuário.

Comment: Ah sim, muito obrigado, consegui aqui! Você saberia como faço para desabilitar o botão do formulário ao aparecer a mensagem? Vou atualizar minha pergunta com os campos.

Answer (score 1):

Para validar é um pouco diferente, assim:

```html
<form action="">
    <input type="email" name="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Aí precisa ver se essa `pattern` está correta.

[Fonte](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp)

Se você não quer que apareça sugestões usa `autocomplete=off`

Para sugestões personalizadas aí usa `Ajax`.

Comment: Eu tinha essa validação, mas como ela "foge" do padrão das outras meu cliente pediu para alterar, ela mostra como se fosse um alert em amarelo e tudo mais, eu gostaria só da mensagem simples em baixo, eu consegui fazer isso já, meu único problema agora é desabilitar o botão se essa mensagem for acionada.

Comment: Veja, eu creio que deva retornar sua questão para o estado anterior, e abrir uma nova

Comment: Ok, vou fazer isso então, eu fiz isso pelo fato de evitar muitas postagens e tudo mais.

Comment: Quanto a isso não precisa se preocupar, mas vale dar uma pesquisada para ver se não tem alguma questão parecida